# Transit Clarification

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, transit, myanmar-citizens

I am going to purchase airline tickets from "one travel" online airline ticketing. I am traveling from Doha to Yangon with the transits of Dubai and Kuala Lumpur. Actually, it is two transits trip from Doha to Dubai by Qatar Airways, and from Dubai to Kuala Lumpur and from Kuala Lumpur to Yangon by Malaysia Airlines. The same way for the return. So, basically, 2 airlines will be taken in my trip.

My questions are these, since I am purchasing online tickets,

1. Will I be given single ticket for each flight that I am going take?
2. Do I need to pass immigration to draw my baggage and to check in again to change to Malaysia Airlines in Dubai?
3. Do I require a visa for Dubai airport since I need to pass immigration just to collect my baggage to re-check?
4. Do I have to do the same thing in Kuala Lumpur airport to collect baggage and check-in again to take the next flight to Myanmar?
5. Will I require a visa for Kuala Lumpur again?

I am Myanmar nationality.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you split the questions regarding Dubai and Kuala Lumpur?  There are several with different rules and regulations.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are making one booking for the whole trip through onetravel i would assume you'll get a single ticket for all legs.  Given that Qatar Airways and Malaysian Airlines are [part the same Oneworld](http://www.oneworld.com/member-airlines/overview) alliance, i would expect they have interline agreements to checkthrough your baggage for the whole journey.

If not this [travelSE answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43917/luggage-transfer-in-dubai-between-flights-without-a-visa) covers the process you'll have to go through in Dubai. Have a look at this [Emirates tool to determine transit and visa requirements.](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=MM&NV=Myanmar&AC=QA&AV=Qatar&DC=MM&DV=Myanmar&TC=AE%2CMY&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates%2CMalaysia&h=2e4caed7e1575ee3d77ef08fb72d72546822fe48) In this case it seems unfortunately that you'll need a visa and are [not eligible for a visa on arrival.](http://www.visadubai-online.com/faq/) Also [read this answer about how things can go wrong!](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/can-i-through-check-my-bags-on-separate-bookings-international-flights)

In summary if you make a single booking, with partner airlines you should be fine. Otherwise make sure you have a transit visa. Nevertheless best to check with your airlines, they will be able to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You should be on a single ticket within the oneworld alliance.  [You should not have to collect your luggage and re-check it in despite changing airlines with some exceptions](http://www.oneworld.com/airports-destinations/baggage-information/baggage-queries-during-travel):

> If you are travelling on connecting oneworld flights, your luggage will be checked through to your final destination at the time of check-in.

The two listed exceptions:

> If the time between connecting oneworld flights is more than 12 hours, you may need to collect your luggage on arrival and check-in again with the outbound carrier.
>
> You may be required to collect and re-check your bags at certain airports due to local security or customs policies.

You don't mention your transfer times, but neither [Dubai](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/airport-guide-dubai/global/en#transfers) nor [Kuala Lumpur](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g298570-i7008-k3981309-Transit_question_do_i_need_to_collect_my_luggage-Kuala_Lumpur_Wilayah_Persekutuan.html) require re-check in of bags for transfers if you do receive a single ticket.

[Neither require visas](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=MM&NV=Myanmar&AC=QA&AV=Qatar&DC=MM&DV=Myanmar&TC=AE%2CMY&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates%2CMalaysia&h=2e4caed7e1575ee3d77ef08fb72d72546822fe48) if you are [transiting without](http://www.klia.com.my/?m=airport&c=info&id=2) [leaving the airport](http://www.dubaifaqs.com/visa-transit-dubai.php).