# Baggage transfer from Dubai airport terminal 2 to terminal 3 for Emirates passenger

Tags: luggage, dxb

I am travelling from Kish to Dubai on Kish Air and from Dubai to Bangalore with Emirates. I want my baggage should transit from Kish Air to Emirates flight ie baggage transfer from Dubai airport terminal 2 to terminal 3 for Emirates,  what are the possible ways to do so ?

Comment: Is this a single booking ? Kish Air isn't part of an alliance with Emirates, so you may have to do that yourself

Answer (score 2):

Your options are:

1. Go through Immigration, collect your bags, transfer, check them in again.  Free but time-consuming and requires a visa for Dubai.
2. Pay [Marhaba Services](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/our-services/meet-greet#Service-tab-2) to do this for you.  Not available for all combinations of airlines and terminals, so check well in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you want transfer your baggage from terminal 2 to terminal 3 you must pay (approximately 300 Dirhams) to baggage transfer desk. After payment only they will transfer your baggage.

Comment: Where is the desk? Do you have more information about this?